# MS DOS command or Java code to Copy a file are directory from one drive to Multiple Drives?

Tags: java, dos

I need to copy a directory from one directory to multiple drives (the drives are external storage devices). After searching I found the MS DOS command `xcopy C:\ F:\ /e`. This command only copies a file to one drive at a time, it doesn't copy to multiple drives. Is there any way to copy a file from one drive to many drives?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to make multiple copies of the file?

Comment: Nope, i need to move a single file from one drive to multiple drive. for example my file in C: drive, i need to move form c: to E:,F:,G:.

Comment: How can you *move* to multiple drives? Moving from one place to another *removes* it from the first place. Anyway this is not a programming question.

Comment: i posted  clearly,,i need to copy "to copy a file form one drive to many drives."

Comment: By using DOS command is it possible. we can copy/move a file form one directory to another ie using xcopy command i can copy a file from C: to F:

Comment: why not multiple copy-calls? `copy c:\myFile d:\myFile` `copy c:\myFile e:\myFile` ... for realizing this automatically: just write your own batch-file

Comment: Are you really still using MS-DOS? I didn't know there was a Java VM for that....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small batch file may help to achieve what you need.

```
set src=%~1

:Loop
    shift
    set dest=%~1
    if "%dest%"=="" goto :EOF
    xcopy "%src%" "%dest%" /E
goto Loop
```

save the code to `%SystemRoot%\system32\mcopy.bat`, then `mcopy some-file e: f:\some-directory g:\some-directory-2 h: i:` ...

Comment: Thanks a lot LiuYan, it saved and satisfies me.. once again thanks